# Numpy: appending items to matrix-like array

Tags: arrays, python-2.7, numpy

I used to code in R and now trying to find my way into python. I have been using lists most of the time but now I need to get things done with numpy. Somehow this seems to work quite differently in comparison to R and most of the time I run into problems of broadcasting input arrays from different shapes. Maybe if I can figure out what's going wrong in the following code, I'll be able to understand better what numpy is trying to do and how I can address certain parts of an array.

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array((1,2,3,4))
b = np.array((2,4,6,8))
c = np.array((3,6,9,12))

myArray = np.asarray((a,b,c))
```

now I would like to append each row on myArray with its mean. I tried this:

```
for i in range(myArray.shape[0]):
    myArray[i] = np.append(myArray[i,:], np.mean(myArray[i,:]))
```

and I get "could not broadcast input array from shape (5) into shape (4). I figure, it tries to squeeze the new item into the old array of size four, whereas I would like to *append* it. How do I do that?

My desired output would look like:

```
[In] print myArray
[Out] [[1.0  2.0  3.0  4.0  2.5]
      [2.0, 4.0, 6.0, 8.0, 5.0]
      [3.0, 6.0, 9.0, 12.0, 7.5]]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get the mean/average values across rows with [`.mean(1)`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/generated/numpy.mean.html) and then stack those alongside the input array as two "columnar blocks" with [`np.column_stack`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.column_stack.html), like so -

```
np.column_stack((myArray,myArray.mean(1)))
```

---

For doing this in a loop, you need to initialize and store, as shown below -

```
m,n = myArray.shape               # Get shape of input array
# Define output array with same rows as input, but one more column in it
myArrayOut = np.zeros((m,n+1))    
for i in range(myArray.shape[0]):
    # Store each row alongwith its mean as the last element
    myArrayOut[i] = np.append(myArray[i,:], np.mean(myArray[i,:]))
```

Comment: I updated the question and added the desired output. column_stack looks great, but can you also apply it in a loop? I might have to add different values to these arrays

Update: ok, I calculated a list "d" that contains all desired values and than column-stacked myArray and d. That works, but I'd have to create a new list for each item to append. Maybe there is an easier way to do it?

Comment: @offeltoffel So, are you looking for list of arrays or a single array as output?

Comment: Single array output would be the most convenient. The idea of "initializing and storing" is great, since I always know the size of the final array, so I can create it in advance and then fill it with the stacked or appended values. Thanks!

Comment: @offeltoffel It would depend on the actual use-case, but for performance (which is why people go for NumPy), I would go with vectorized methods. Please be mindful of that.